# why map on list generates extra []

Tags: maple

Why does

```
 map(x->print(x),[1,2,3]);
```

generate

```
                           1
                           2
                           3
                           []
```

Where did the `[]` come from? According to help, .

```
 The map commands apply fcn to the operands or elements of expr.
```

and

```
  op([1,2,3]);
```

gives

```
  1, 2, 3
```

But it seems here that fcn was also applied to the list itself, i.e. `op(0,[1,2,3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behaviour from `map`.

The `print` command returns `NULL`.

```
foo := print(1);
                      1

                    foo :=

lprint(foo);
  NULL
```

The `map` command applied to a list will always return a list. The return value of `map` is not the return value of any of the calls to the first argument (operator) passed to `map`.

Let's make another example, with another procedure which returns `NULL`.

```
f := proc(x) NULL; end proc:

map(f, [1,2,3]);
                      []
```

So every entry of the original list `[1,2,3]` gets replaced by `NULL`, which results in an expression sequence of three `NULL`s, which ends up being `NULL`. So the final result from applying `map` here is `[NULL]` which produces the empty list `[]`.

```
bar := NULL, NULL, NULL;
                    bar :=

lprint(bar);            
  NULL

[ NULL, NULL, NULL ];
                      []
```

If you don't want to see the empty list returned from `map` on your example then terminate the statement with a full colon.

If you do it using `seq` instead of `map` then the return value will be the just `NULL` (since it produces the expression-sequence of three `NULL`s, which as shown above becomes just `NULL`).

```
seq(print(x), x=[1,2,3]);
                                           1

                                           2

                                           3

lprint(%);               
  NULL
```